# Submitting a form without page reload

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I don't know Ajax or PHP but I want to submit this form without page refresh and also want to appear check icon beside the submit button. How can I do this?

```
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="email" value="e-mail address" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: `"How can I do this?"` -> researching this site and trying something for yourself before asking. The ***Related*** column here at the right has plenty of similar topics.

Comment: yes i saw them but didnt understand many of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
function xyz(){
var email_val=$('#email').val();
$.post("ajax.php",{"email":email_val},function(data){
  if(data) {
      $('#message').html('Data submit successfully');
      $('#email').val('');
    }
    else{
       $('#message').html('Failed');
    }
});
}

</script>


<form id="form" action="" method="post" onsubmit="xyz()">
   <input type="text" id="email" value="e-mail address" />
   <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
   <span id="message"></span>
</form>
```

ajax.php

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['email'])){
     //Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not aware of AJAX and PHP but still you have to submit a form without page reload then follow this tutorial.. do some home works

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/